# Дублирующиеся записи при совмещении двух таблиц MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

Добрый день. Реализовать пытаюсь систему "лайков". Есть новость со своим id в базе данных MySQL и текстом. Есть отдельная таблица для оценок. В ней три 4 поля. id персональное, id новости, к которой этот "лайк" будет привязан ip адрес и значение (1 или 0). Проблема заключается в том, что записей с оценкой больше в количестве, чем сама новость. Если совмещать две таблицы по JOIN, то появляется дубль той-же новости ровно столько раз, сколько "лайков" было выставлено. Каким образом это реализовать через PHP (какой запрос в бд сделать и как его вывести)? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А какой запрос вы уже пытались отправить для получения данных?

Comment: Для одного запроса делайте группировку по ид новости и суммирование по значению лайка. Если нужна подробная информация по лайкам, то отдельный запрос по новостям и отдельный по лайкам.

Comment: Привязывать "лайки" к IP?! Странно. У нас 500 сотрудников работают через один IP. ИМХО привязка должна быть к пользователю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, зачем поле `значение`. Если пользователь не ставил лайк, просто не записывать его и все. По идее должно быть так:

Таблица **news**

```
id, text
```

Таблица **news_likes**

```
id, news_id, user_id, ip
```

Ну и запрос, например, такой:

```
SELECT news.id, COUNT(news_likes.id) AS likes
FROM news
LEFT JOIN news_likes ON news.id = news_likes.news_id
GROUP BY news.id
```